# Adding Index Page in PDF created with Apache FOP

Tags: java, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have written an application using Apache FOP, that generates PDFs with many multiple Chapters. Is there a way, by which I could know - which chapter appears on which page. Actually, I need to create index in the beginning, that tells which chapter appears on which page.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put an ID on the element you need to know the page number of, and then reference it with `<fo:page-number-citation ref-id="id"/>`.

Example:

1. Put an ID with an automatically generated id on each block that contains a title of a chapter:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="chapter">
       <fo:block id="{generate-id(.)}">
           <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
       </fo:block>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```
2. Then, reference that ID you gave the block when looping over the same input elements at the start where your index is:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="chapter">
       <fo:block id="{generate-id(.)}">
           <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{generate-id(.)}"/>
       </fo:block>
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```

It really doesn't matter whether your index (which is more like a table of contents here) is generated before the actual content or not, as the IDs are calculated by the XSL parser, and FOP resolves these references after the page layout (and thus page numbers) has been determined.